# Angular ng rx store get saved Object from map() and use it in tap() inside Effect

Tags: angular, ngrx

im working in angular 13 project im using ngrx store and it works fine.
my issue is that i want to get the if from my saved object and show it in the toastr after save succes.

this is my effect code :

```
saveDemandeEffect: Observable<DemandeActions> = createEffect(

    () => this.effectActions.pipe(


        ofType(EnvelopeActionsTypes.SAVE_ENVELOPE),

        mergeMap((action: DemandeActions) => {

            return this.demandeService.saveDemande(action.payload)
                .pipe(
                    map((demande) => {
                        return new SaveDemandeActionSuccess(demande);
                    }),
                    tap(
                        () => {
                            // here i want to get saved demande object then demande.id to show it in the toastr msg bellow
                            this.toastr.success("message", "Confirmation")
                            this.router.navigate(['/envelopes']);
                        }
                    ),
                    catchError((err) => of(new SaveDemandeActionError(err.message)))
                )
        })
    )

);
```

do you have any idea how i can acheive this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try by removing the nested pipes and use `switchMap` instead `mergeMap`.

```
    saveDemandeEffect: Observable<DemandeActions> = createEffect(
        () => this.effectActions.pipe(
            ofType(EnvelopeActionsTypes.SAVE_ENVELOPE),    
            switchMap((action: DemandeActions) => this.demandeService.saveDemande(action.payload)),
            tap((demande)=> {
               this.toastr.success("message Id: " + demande.id, "Confirmation")
               this.router.navigate(['/envelopes']);
            }),
            map((demande) =>new SaveDemandeActionSuccess(demande)),
            
           catchError((err) => of(new SaveDemandeActionError(err.message))
        );
```

Comment: @Abdel Valdez . what about showing demande.id in my this.toastr.success("message", "Confirmation") ? . thanks

Comment: tap((demande)=> {
               this.toastr.success("message"+demande,id, "Confirmation")
               this.router.navigate(['/envelopes']);
            }),

Comment: it's not workin because it consider the demande object like SaveDemandeActionSuccess

Comment: Then add the tap before the map

Comment: @Abdelthanks. could you please explain to me why it works when i put tap before map ?

Comment: because a tap is going to get the value that is returning the previous function  in this case is call to the service. then right after you can map this information. if my answer works for you please mask as +1 and the correct answer

Comment: @Abdel valdez thanks a lot . could you please modify your answer by addingin tap before map then i will accept it as right answer.Regards

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245600/discussion-between-abel-valdez-and-james).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? If you API on save returns the demande object, then you can take the required action in the map function itself

```
saveDemandeEffect: Observable<DemandeActions> = createEffect(

    () => this.effectActions.pipe(


        ofType(EnvelopeActionsTypes.SAVE_ENVELOPE),

        mergeMap((action: DemandeActions) => {

            return this.demandeService.saveDemande(action.payload)
                .pipe(
                    map((demande) => {
                        // you can get your demande id here ?
                        this.toastr.success("message", "Confirmation")
                        this.router.navigate(['/envelopes']);
                        return new SaveDemandeActionSuccess(demande);
                    }),
                    catchError((err) => of(new SaveDemandeActionError(err.message)))
                )
        })
    )

);
```